# Firebase signInWithCustomToken using token generated by AWS Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-authentication, amazon-cognito

In my app, users may authenticate with AWS Cognito and have access to AWS resources.
Users sign in and get access token to use as Authorization with Http calls to API Gateway.

Now, i want to also use Firebase services like database and storage. I understand that there is a method to sign a user with a [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) from other authentication server. Tried to do that with my tokens from Cognito:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(tokenFromCognito)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:success");
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Both id and access tokens not working. Got this error:

```
2019-04-19 18:15:35.467 16678-16678/com.app.example E/MainActivity: signInWithCustomToken:failure
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdr.zzb(Unknown Source:30)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzey.zza(Unknown Source:16)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeo.zzc(Unknown Source:33)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.onFailure(Unknown Source:49)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:18)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:690)
```

The mentioned tokens are valid JWT tokens and were decoded properly at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

Obviously i'm missing something, why would the FirebaseAuth even accept my tokens? Do i need to change some settings at the Firebase project side?

**UPDATE:**

Following [Arka Mukherjee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764383/firebase-signinwithcustomtoken-using-token-generated-by-aws-cognito#comment98215505_55764383) comment, i was able to generate new token with `firebase-admin.auth().createCustomToken(...)` that is valid for firebase `signInWithCustomToken` method.

Only thing is that prefer not to handle two types of tokens in my app (and server).

These are the tokens, decoded by [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/):

> Cognito token:

```
{
    "sub": "some uuid of the user",
    "cognito:groups": [
        "DefaultGroup"
    ],
    "event_id": "9055ddd1-6221-11e9-bf0b-cd63ab32d87b",
    "token_use": "access",
    "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
    "auth_time": 1555623190,
    "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/pool_id",
    "exp": 1555842517,
    "iat": 1555838917,
    "jti": "243b72c1-4c4b-43a8-9d41-c4311f02794b",
    "client_id": "android app client id",
    "username": "testUser"
}
```

> Firebase token:

```
{
    "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
    "iat": 1555840515,
    "exp": 1555844115,
    "iss": "firebase-adminsdk-stint@projectID.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "sub": "firebase-adminsdk-stint@projectID.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "uid": "testUser"
}
```

If anyone can help me figure out how to modify the Cognito token to be valid for firebase without generating a new one, maybe with [PreTokenGeneration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) trigger of Cognito.
Again, the current state is working but not very maintainable.

Comment: Just a thing, can you try manually creating a Custom Token according to their documentation, and give this code a whirl? I think Cognito's Token might be running into scope/claim limitations, as certain parameters in the token are read only.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ArkaMukherjee.
Listened to your advice and added firebase token generation logic to my aws server.
And it's working, i can sign in with the new token and use firebase services as an authenticated user. Wish there was a way without generating another token after already got one though.

Comment: You could modify certain parameters of Cognito's Token using the pre-Token Generation Lambda trigger. It might not work out, but could you give it a shot? I'm uncertain what Firebase demands, as I have experience developing only using Cognito.

Comment: Maybe with more info? updated my question.